# Redirecting /page/xx/ if 404 - IIS / WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, iis, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

Running WordPress (PHP / MySQL) on Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS.

After moving my blog from an ASP.net solution to WordPress, I set up a number of IIS redirects to help to cut down the Google crawl errors.  I'm a WordPress operator, not a developer, but I do have the redirects working using URL Rewriting / regex, etc.  I'm not totally unfamiliar with the concepts.

Now, I've moved to a revamped theme, etc., but still on WordPress.  Everything is pretty much OK, but I'm getting a lot of 404 crawl errors for pages that no longer exist due to changes in the way I'm displaying archives.

For example, /author/joe/page/150/ now 404s. There are many of these across numerous folders (/author/, /tag/, etc.)

I cannot simply redirect /page/ as (for example) /author/joe/page/100/ is a valid page.

What I would like to do is to say, "if */page/xxx = 404, then redirect to /page/", or something like that, but I'm unclear on how to proceed.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can add code to functions.php
Hook into the 'template_redirect' action. See [documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).

Example from link with little modification:

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    if( is_404() ) {
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $search = '/author/joe/page/';
        if ( strpos( $search, $url ) !== false ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/page/' ), 301 ); // or w/e where you want to redirect
        }
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```